# Using page slug to open a specific tab in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, slug

I'm trying to open a specific bootstrap tab on a webpage using page slugs. For example:

```
www.mysite.domain/profile/#my_courses
```

will open profile page with courses history tab active

Here is my code:

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile,  name='profile'),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<page_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.profile,  name='profile'),
]
```

#### view.py profile

```
@login_required
def profile(request, page_slug=None):
    profile   = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=request.user.username)
    courses   = Course.objects.filter(trainer__in = [profile]).order_by('start_time')
    trainings = Course.objects.filter(students__in = [profile]).order_by('start_time')

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context = {'courses': courses,
                                                               'trainings': trainings,
                                                               'page_slug': page_slug,})
```

#### profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block headers %}
{{ block.super }}
<link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "accounts/css/profile.css" %}'/>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<ul class='nav nav-tabs navbar-inverse'>
    <li class='active'><a href= '#profile' data-toggle='tab'>{% trans 'Profile' %}</a></li>
    <li><a href='#trainings' data-toggle='tab'>{% trans 'My Trainings' %}</a></li>
    {% if user.profile.is_trainer %}
    <li><a href='#courses' data-toggle='tab'>{% trans 'My Courses' %}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>

<div id='content' class='tab-content'>
    <div class='tab-pane fade active in' id='profile'></div>
    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='my_trainings'>
        <ul class='courses__container'></ul>
    </div>
    {% if user.profile.is_trainer %}
    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='courses'>
        <ul class='courses__container'></ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Since javascript on user-side can't understand django template tags I can't do this in javascript. How can I add/remove `active` class in `<li>` and `<div>` tags in django template?

Answer (score 1):

In the URL

```
www.mysite.domain/profile/#my_courses
```

`#my_courses` is a *fragment*, not a slug. URL fragments only exist in the browser, they are not sent to the web server, and so you URL routing and templates will never see them.

When the user visits that url, what is sent to the server is

```
www.mysite.domain/profile/
```

And that's the page that is returned. You'd need JavaScript on the page to inspect the full URL (through document.location.href) and update the page accordingly.

A slug, on the other hand, is not separated by a `#` character, and forms part of the URL that *is* sent to the server. That can be seen by Django, and inform the view as to what to render in the template. You would need to redesign your URLs to take advantage of that, though.